# How to make a string length limited to a specific number?

Tags: c#

In C#, if we have a class '**Employee**' and it will have a property called '**Code**' that must consist of 7 characters in the following format: **(A-Z) + (1-9)+(0-1)+(0001-9999)**

for example **'Code' = A501234** or **Z910002**

So if we make a property '**Code**' in the Class '**Employee**' is there any way to force developer when '**Code**' is set, to check if it is in the prev format or at least force him to set it to 7 characters, so that, for example, it can cause compiler or build errors?

Thanks in advance for expected cooperation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating parameter values/formats at *runtime* could also be accomplished using the 
[Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203309.aspx) from the MS Enterprise library or something similar.

You would basically specify your validation rules using attributes,

```
[StringLengthValidator(1, 50, Ruleset = "RuleSetA", 
           MessageTemplate = "Last Name must be between 1 and 50 characters")]
public string LastName
{
    get { return lastName; }
    set { lastName = value; }
}

[RelativeDateTimeValidator(-120, DateTimeUnit.Year, -18, 
               DateTimeUnit.Year, Ruleset="RuleSetA", 
               MessageTemplate="Must be 18 years or older.")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth
{
    get { return dateOfBirth; }
    set { dateOfBirth = value; }
}

[RegexValidator(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", 
             Ruleset = "RuleSetA")]
public string Email
{
    get { return email; }
    set { email = value; }
}
```

Code snippet from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139849.aspx. Don't know of anything that would check at compile time though.

Answer (score 3):

```
public struct Code
{
    public readonly String Value;

    public Code(String value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        if (value.Length != 7) throw new ArgumentException("Must be 7 characters long.");

        // Other validation.

        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public string Code
{
    set
    {
        if (value.Length != 7)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...)
        }
        // other validation
        _code = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the setter section of the property.

```
public string Code
{
    set 
    {
        if (value.Length != 7)
            throw new Exception("Length must be 7.");
        _code = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the setter for the property, you can check the length and throw an error if it is != 7

To check the exact format, you can use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A [Regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) can validate the length and the format all at once.

```
class Employee
{
   // ...
   private string code;
   public string Code
   {
      set
      {
         Regex regex = new Regex("^[A-Z]{1}[1-9]{1}[0,1]{1}[0-9]{3}[1-9]{1}$");
         Match match = regex.Match(value);
         if (!match.Success)
         {
            throw new ArgumentException("Employee must be in ... format");
         }            
         code = value;
       }
    }
   // ...
}
```